# Problem looking at tables within ESRI geodatbase

Tags: qgis, esri-geodatabase

I installed the most recent OSGeo4W with QGIS 1.8.0 and GDAL 1.9.2 on my Windows 7 PC.

I can load an ESRI geodatabase (.gdb file) and I can get the window 
"Select vector layers to add".
When I click on any of the layers, however, I get the message "qgis.exe has stopped working"

Any idea where the problem might be?

Comment: what version of esri geodatabase are you using v9 or v10?